# Who fasted with Ester?

Tags: midrash, fast-days, megillat-esther, slave-serve-eved-avadim, tractate-megillah

The *Bavli*, *M'gila*, says that the seven servants that *Ester* had while in *Hegay*'s harem were שהיתה מונה בהן ימי שבת, used by *Ester* to count the days of the week. *Rashi* explains שהיתה משרתת לה אחת באחד בשבת ואחת בשני בשבת ואחת בשלישי בשבת וכן כולן וכשהגיע יום שפחה של שבת יודעת שהיום שבת, that one would serve her on Sunday, another on Monday, another on Tuesday, and so on, so that, when the Saturday servant arrived, she [*Ester*] would know it's *Shabas*.

In *Ester* 4:16, *Ester* says she and her servants will fast three days. (She doesn't say *all* her servants will.)

- Did she still have a servant per day of the week? (Obviously I'm asking according to the *midrash* cited above.)
- If so, did all of them fast for three days, or did each fast only her day?

Comment: But getting 10 people to "fast" for .3 days each, for example, is not the same thing as one or multiple people actually fasting for 3 days. The two are not just quantitatively, but qualitatively different. The implication of "will do so" is to fast for 3 consecutive days.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56115/who-were-the-girls-that-fasted-with-esther

Comment: I repeat that this is almost certainly the best you will find. The chance of anyone connecting the Midrash about _meshartot_ to the verse about _ne'arot_ is quite slim, (I think). I would wager to guess, you wont find anything about it pre-20th century. So no really authoritative sources. At most, you'll find someones guess, since there is no reason to assume that the author of that Midrash even had an opinion about this.